# Restricting access to S3 objects unless url is signed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a unique bucket for my private files on S3. This bucket is configured to block all public access. My application is configured to upload files to this s3 bucket with no public read access and I can confirm that the permissions on the objects reflect that this is working (i.e. there are no permissions given to the public on the objects that are uploaded).

Despite all of these measures to restrict public access to these files, these files are still visible to the public. I think that my IAM settings may be overriding the ACL setting as well as the bucket settings. I'm not sure which IAM setting to change or if changes may negatively impact other parts of my application, so I'd like to restrict access to this 'private bucket' with a bucket policy if possible.

This is what I've started with for a bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "My Special Bucket Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAccesstoAllFiles",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_private_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this blocks access to objects in this 'private bucket' even with a signed url.

Please note that I've been able to generate signed urls successfully. They expire in 60 seconds just as I've configured them.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: All my files are being uploaded like this:

[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All buckets and objects are **private by default**. So normally you don't need any policy on them. In your case any access is denied, because [`Deny` always wins over any `Allow`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html):

> Remember, an explicit deny in any of these policies overrides the allow.

Thus, there is no way to enable any public access to your objects due to your `Deny`, and no pre-signed url will change that.

Normally what you do is that you get rid of your policy, and rely on default behavior that the buckets and objects are private. In that case, the pre-signed url will work.

Comment: I've revised my post with a screenshot. Can you have a look. Do you suppose I need to prevent read access on the object / object ACL even for the object owner (my application) so that only signed urls will work? Would this be done on the IAM policy?

Comment: @JasonHoward Yes. You remove your deny policy which blocks everything. No one will be able to read your objects unless you explicitly allow for that (all objects and buckets are private by default) through IAM policies or S3 pre-signed urls.

Comment: Ok, i'll try this. thanks!

Comment: @JasonHoward Also by default [S3 Block Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access/) is also enabled, so this is an extra layer of protection.

Comment: It went excellent. I realized that when the files were noted as being private in s3, they were, in fact, private. In other words, if I removed the perameters after .jpg in the file name, the files couldn't be accessed. Not trying this before was what as causing the confusion.

Comment: @JasonHoward glad it worked out. If any of the answers provided was helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. Buckets created in AWS in default settings are always private and their objects are not accessible via their links. I think you have mixed up some links that make you believe that your objects are still visible :)
2. You do not need to have an explicit policy to deny all the access to
   your S3 objects.

I would recommend you to remove the policy that you have attached to your bucket and then test again if the public links to your objects work (they shouldn't if your bucket is made via default settings). Once that part is clear, your pre-signed URLs should work!

Comment: Thanks Anss. You are correct. What I was missing was the piece of the puzzle that allowed me to determine if they were public.